# how to send image from one activity to another, using listview item

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, android-listview, android-activity

problem in sending image from one activity to another but able to send text to another activity, placing some source code with file name please see and correct the mistake, if possible so please writedown the required code because i am facing this problem for last two days, i have submitted this question 3 times in stackoverflow but i am not getting good answer, please someone write correct things which i need to do and write required code for me, but here i am placing some code of mine:

MainActivity Code:

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
             // getting values from selected ListItem
                String title = ((TextView) view.findViewById
          (R.id.title)).getText().toString();
                String artist = ((TextView) view.findViewById
          (R.id.artist)).getText().toString();
                String duration = ((TextView) view.findViewById
          (R.id.duration)).getText().toString();
                byte[] image = null;
                Bitmap thumb_url = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray
          (image, 0, image.length);


            //  Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray
          (array, 0, array.length);

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent
          (getApplicationContext(),    SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, title);
                in.putExtra(KEY_ARTIST, artist);
                in.putExtra(KEY_DURATION, duration);
                in.putExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL, thumb_url);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });     
    }   
    }
```

ReceivingActivity Code:

```
public class SingleMenuItemActivity  extends Activity {

// XML node keys
private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
private static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
private static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
private static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);

    // getting intent data
    Intent in = getIntent();

    // Get XML values from previous intent
    String title = in.getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE);
    String artist = in.getStringExtra(KEY_ARTIST);
    String duration = in.getStringExtra(KEY_DURATION);

    ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.thumb_url);
    Object thumb_url = null;
    View bitmap = null;
    bitmap.setBackgroundResource((Integer) thumb_url);   
    // Displaying all values on the screen
    TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
    TextView lblCost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email_label);
    TextView lblDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_label);

   //what code to write for image here 

    lblName.setText(title);
    lblCost.setText(artist);
    lblDesc.setText(duration);

}
 }
```

XML File Code:

```
    <ImageView     
        android:id="@+id/thumb_url"   
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:src="@drawable/rihanna"/>


   <TextView android:id="@+id/name_label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:textColor="#43bd00"/>

      <TextView android:id="@+id/email_label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#acacac"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/mobile_label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can get image from intent.

Answer (score 1):

I might be mistaken, but I think there's a limit on size of the objects you try to pass with intent (failed binder transaction error?).

The best variant will be to store this image somewhere (memory or disk cache) and pass only the image link to your activity, so it will retrieve image from cache. Even when second activity restartsб you can easily save the link somewhere(onSaveInstanceState) without operating with raw bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1.

> Use Intent in = new Intent (your activity.this,SingleMenuItemActivity.class);

instead of

> Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SingleMenuItemActivity.class);

2.

```
Intent in = getIntent();

    // Get XML values from previous intent
    String title = in.getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE);
    String artist = in.getStringExtra(KEY_ARTIST);
    String duration = in.getStringExtra(KEY_DURATION);
    Bitmap bitmap =(Bitmap) in.getParcelableExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL);

    ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.thumb_url);


    // Displaying all values on the screen
    TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
    TextView lblCost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email_label);
    TextView lblDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_label);

    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 

    lblName.setText(title);
    lblCost.setText(artist);
    lblDesc.setText(duration);

}
```

Comment: What is the use of Object thumb_url = null;
    View bitmap = null;
    bitmap.setBackgroundResource((Integer) thumb_url);?

Comment: Thank You,So nice of you, you have solved 95% problem of mine, such a useful code but still getting a problem, if i write this code:- android:src="@drawable/rihanna" in xml file, then only getting that particular image everytime click on listview item but if i delete this line then i am getting blank space at image view location so please tell me what i need to write in singleviewitem.xml file in ImageView to fetch listview item image...Thanks again

Comment: @AshaSoman yes but im getting this error : "Key thumb_url expected Parcelable but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned." the code is same.

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap implements Parcelable, so you could always pass it in the intent:

```
Intent in = new Intent
      (getApplicationContext(),    SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, title);
            in.putExtra(KEY_ARTIST, artist);
            in.putExtra(KEY_DURATION, duration);
            in.putExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL, thumb_url);
            startActivity(in);
```

and retrieve it on the other end:

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: yes but im getting this error : "Key thumb_url expected Parcelable but value was a java.lang.String. The default value <null> was returned." the code is same.